# Problems with gridspec plotting with APLpy

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, astropy, aplpy

So I'm attempting to plot to fits images (identical fits images) with some annotations provided by a DS9 region file using APLpy:

My script is as follows:

```
import aplpy

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

from astropy.io import fits

matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=8)
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=8)
#matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
#matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
#matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['grid.alpha'] = 0.3

nullfmt = pyplot.NullFormatter()

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(26,12))

gridspec_layout = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)
#gridspec_layout.update(hspace=0.0, wspace=0.005)

M33_galax = aplpy.FITSFigure('/Users/.../SDSS_g_c_rescale.fits', figure=fig, subplot=list(gridspec_layout[0].get_position(fig).bounds), dimensions=[0, 1], slices=[0])
M33_stars = aplpy.FITSFigure('/Users/.../SDSS_g_c_rescale.fits', figure=fig, subplot=list(gridspec_layout[1].get_position(fig).bounds), dimensions=[0, 1], slices=[0])
#dimensions=[0, 1], slices=[1]

M33_galax.show_regions('SDSS_galaxy_match.reg')
#M33_stars.show_regions('')

M33_galax.set_tick_labels_format(xformat='hh:mm:ss.ss',yformat='dd:mm:ss')
M33_galax.set_tick_labels_font(size='x-small')
M33_galax.axis_labels.set_ytext(r'$\delta\,,\mathrm{Dec}\,\mathrm{(J2000)}$')
M33_galax.axis_labels.set_xtext(r'$\alpha\,,\mathrm{RA}\,\mathrm{(J2000)}$')
M33_galax.axis_labels.set_font(size='small')
M33_galax.axis_labels.set_ypad(10)
M33_galax.axis_labels.set_xpad(10)
M33_galax.add_grid()
M33_galax.grid.set_alpha(0.1)

M33_stars.set_tick_labels_format(xformat='hh:mm:ss.ss',yformat='dd:mm:ss')
M33_stars.set_tick_labels_font(size='x-small')
M33_stars.axis_labels.set_ytext(r'$\delta\,,\mathrm{Dec}\,\mathrm{(J2000)}$')
M33_stars.axis_labels.set_xtext(r'$\alpha\,,\mathrm{RA}\,\mathrm{(J2000)}$')
M33_stars.axis_labels.set_font(size='small')
M33_stars.axis_labels.set_ypad(10)
M33_stars.axis_labels.set_xpad(10)
M33_stars.add_grid()
M33_stars.grid.set_alpha(0.1)

pyplot.show()
```

However, I am finding the following is the output:

[image]

Would anyone know where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @DavidG Errrr, within the two plotting regions I should be seeing the two fits files that I'm loading. Specifically the SDSS g filter image of a galaxy...(both the same) loaded twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `show_grayscale` or `show_colorscale` to display the images, e.g.:

```
M33_galax.show_grayscale()
```